Can you explain why the results of calculating L-inf norm of a 1-dim and the same 2-dim arrays are different in Numpy?
Please see the code below.
import numpy as np

a = np.array([-1, -3, -1, -9, 2])
b = np.array([[-1, -3, -1, -9, 2]])

print("Infinity norm of a:", np.linalg.norm(a, ord=np.inf))
print("Infinity norm of b:", np.linalg.norm(b, ord=np.inf))


The output (Google Colab) is:
Infinity norm of a: 9.0
Infinity norm of b: 16.0

Numpy version is 1.25.2
Google Colab Python version is 3.10.12
Please see the description above. I expected the same results. But L-inf norm of 1-D and 2-D arryas are apparently different.
EDIT: Thanks for referring me to the numpy documentation and the table therein. However, is this what Gilbert Strang would expect to get? A row vector and a column vector and their equivalent 1-dim array should have the same L-inf norm. Is this not confusing?

Read the docs before asking? [ask]

This is the expected behaviour. See the manual

np.linalg.norm(b, ord=np.inf, axis=1)) to get the "same" value.

If what you want is abs(x).max(), just use that?

b is not a 1-dim array; b.shape == (1, 5), a.shape == (5,)

"A row vector and a column vector and their equivalent 1-dim array should have the same L-inf norm. Is this not confusing?": for numpy, a vector has only one dimension. What you call a "column vector", numpy calls a 1-column matrix (shape = (N, 1)). A "row vector" is a 1-row matrix (shape = (1, N)). The documentation correctly describes the behavior of linalg.norm for all three cases (even though this is different from what you and Dr. Strang expect)

numpy's handling of (n,), (n,1), (1,n) shaped arrays has parallels in formal linear algebra, but is not exactly the same.  MATLAB, where everything is 2d, is closer to linear algebra.  numpy is multidimensional - 0,1,2,...n dimensions are allowed.

The table in the docs directly gives a rationale for this difference!
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html



ord
norm for matrices
norm for vectors




inf
max(sum(abs(x), axis=1))
max(abs(x))



As @Julien notes in the comments, you can expressly set the 2D axis to achieve a comparable result
>>> np.linalg.norm(b, ord=np.inf)
16.0
>>> np.linalg.norm(b, ord=np.inf, axis=1)
array([9.])

or, perhaps most clearly, manipulating the internal inf norm function
>>> from numpy import *  # clobber builtin sum() thanks @Julien again!
>>> sum(abs(b), axis=0)  # max:  9
array([1, 3, 1, 9, 2])
>>> sum(abs(b), axis=1)  # max: 16
array([16])

